# Error al ejecutar npm install undefined ls-remote

Tags: nodejs, npm, github

Estoy intentando ejecutar por primera vez el `npm install` y estoy teniendo varios problemas. Con la última versión no pude, así que utilicé esta en recomendación.

Probé eliminando el `package-lock`, la carpeta, utilizando código `npm init`, pero nada.

**CMD:**

```
npm WARN deprecated angular-tree-component@7.2.1: Library moved to @circlon/angular-tree-component
npm WARN deprecated angular2-useful-swiper@8.0.1-beta.1: this package has now been renamed to ngx-useful-swiper please use that package from now on
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated ng5-slider@1.2.6: ng5-slider is now replaced by @angular-slider/ngx-slider targeting Angular 6+ and rxjs 6+
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: Desinstala node js y vuelve a instalarlo, después de esto, instala npm

Comment: eso lo hice ya, primero desinstale y volvi a instalar ultima version, corri comando pero seguia con error asi que desinstale otra vez e instale version 12.18.3

Comment: Instalaste la version current de node js? no es recomendable instalar la última, ya que esta no esta bien configurada para usuarios comunes, es una versión que le falta bastantes parches y actualizaciones

Comment: ahora mismo estoy con la version 12.18.3, no la current

Comment: Prueba con esto. npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sass

Comment: Los mensajes de advertencia son claros: *deprecated* que significa *obsoleto*. ¿Exactamente qué estás tratando de instalar? ¿Has revisado si el proyecto o repositorio que intentas instalar está actualizado? Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! deberias mostrar el package.json, decirnos que paquetes tratas de instalar, probar instalar de a uno y verificar cual es el que esta deprecado....

Answer (score 1):

Bueno aqui hay que considerar varios puntos:

1. ¿Como instalaste node?

Puedes probar instalando NVM para reinstalar node de manera segura siguiendo los siguientes comandos:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

O puedes probar con WGET

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Para poder instalar node utilizando nvm, utiliza el comando `nvm install node` algo asi como:

```
$ nvm install node                                                             
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.1831/node-v12.18.3-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Now using node v12.18.3 (npm v5.3.0)

$ node --version                                                               
v12.18.31
```

Toda la información sobre NVM aqui https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating

Luego de esto, verifica con un `node -v && npm -v`

Otra opción es con el instalador del sitio oficial https://nodejs.org/es/download/

O si estas en Mac, ejecuta `brew install node` para que se reinstale, despues ejecuta `brew doctor && brew cleanup`

2. Si ya reinstalaste y no funciona, prueba con los comandos:

2.1: `npm cache clean -f`

2.2: `rm -rf node_modules`

2.3: `npm i`

Si aun asi el problema persiste, instala Node en su version V11.X, busca el instalador aqui:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/

Comment: ¿Porqué asumes que el OP utiliza un ambiente *nix? Nada de eso aparece en su pregunta, por lo cual, si bien tu respuesta es válida para ambientes *nix, no necesariamente aplique para el OP. Por otro lado, no parece que el problema esté ni en NPM ni en Node, sino en las dependencias de lo que el OP está tratando de instalar.

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que el comando ls-remote sea de git y el cual no tengas instalado.

Si usas una imagen docker de alpine trata de instalar git:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache git
```

Caso contrario instala GIT como normalmente instalas programas, eso ya dependerá de que sistema operativo estés usando.

https://medium.com/anna-coding/solution-for-npm-err-enoent-undefined-ls-remote-h-t-18ab6f8274af